# Is it a good idea to store shopping carts in database with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am developing an e-commerce website and I am expecting the users to visit the website from both mobiles and computers, so I can't store the cart in a session like in darryldecode/cart

Is it a good practice to store the cart in the database ?

like this

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cart', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onUpdate('cascade');

    });
}
```

However, I have a cart that works with $.ajax that store the cart immediately in a session when the user clicks "add to cart" button. Is there any good alternatives ?
Can the cart in darryldecode/cart be stored in the database directly?

Comment: If a user is logged in, you can store their cart in the DB, yes. Why would that be bad practice?

Comment: I have a mini cart that follows the user in all pages

Comment: This question can't be answered generally. It can be a good idea, it can be outright bad. Why do you think this very specific question can be answered on Stackoverflow? What are you specifically looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by this very specific question can't be answered on Stackoverflow, I want a useful piece of code to make the data floating better, I work for a company and they expect a huge data traffic and Laravel has many options for storing the data between both the server and client side

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart#storage), you can store the cart in the database, so the fact that the author explicitly have support for it, I think you could consider this a potential good idea.

Comment: The potential bad, is that sessions are usually short lived, often 20 minutes, whereas that example is 30 days, meaning you are storing 2,000+ times the amount of data of a session